# I am using an angular mat-stepper, however all of my components inside the stepper are non-responsive

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I am using an angular mat-stepper, however, all of my components inside the stepper are non-responsive when the screen size changes. to my understanding, angular components are responsive by design. any help on this question or how to resolve will be appreciated

Comment: Please provide with a piece of code so that we are all in the same page.